# Google Analytics Goal Funnel Count has number differences with Production Data

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics

I have this funnel visualization problem in Google Analytics. I have set up the funnel using the virtual pageview like so:

[image: The google analytics goal]

So basically what it tracks is that in activity page, when user clicks a button, it will show up a modal for registration and hits the /activity/virtual/open-volunteer-modal. After they fill out the forms, they click Register, and it will hits the /activity/virtual/submit-volunteer-modal.

Everything was fine, until I saw some difference in GA and Production values.

[image: The GA values]

In GA, there are 3000 users that filled out the forms and submit their data. I was totally happy seeing this, but:

[image: The DB values]

In Production DB, I only got 1906 users submitting their data.

I checked the code, and there is nothing wrong with it. It basically send a virtual page view when the value has been validated, so my question is how is this possible and is there any way to fix this? Or is it just intended behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, I found that some of the buttons that has open-volunteer-modal event is redirecting to submit-volunteer-modal. Hence, the submit-volunteer-modal value was bigger than the open.

Should have sipped some coffee first before working.